# JQuery - get attr/text from HTML string in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML string that I'm passing through a function and I want to be able to perform Jquery methods on that variable from inside the function - such as `.attr('href')` or `.text()`.  I'm sure there is a simple solution for this and something more elegant then temporarily appending the DOM.

**HTML**

```
<div class="here"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
link = '<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>';

// This works
$('.here').html(link);
works = $('.here').text();
console.log(works);

// This doesn't
not = link.text();
console.log(not);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfgYK/

Comment: Because String object doesn't have `text` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a jQuery object from `link` in order to use jQuery methods on it. Try:

```
not = $(link).text();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/dfgYK/1/

Depending on what you're doing with `link`, it might be beneficial to do this earlier in your code so that you can just use something like:

```
var $link = $(link);
console.log(link.text());
```

Comment: duh, knew it had to be something simple I was forgetting, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a jQuery object that is not part of the DOM by passing a string in:

```
link = $('<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>');
```

Then, jQuery methods will work on it:

```
var text = link.text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the link with jQuery instead:

```
var link = $('<a />', {
    href: "http://www.google.com",
    text: "Google"
});
```

Then you can access it's properties with `link.text()` like you wanted.